# is it possible to join a date column and a string column for year?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pretty ugly database and I cannot change the structure of it but I'm trying to do a join on a date column.

One table has a normal date column whereas another column has 2011 as a int "2,011" and so on. Is there a way to join them?

I tried this:

```
CAST(date_trunc('year', table1.date)  AS string) = table2."year"
```

I have also tried :

```
 CAST(date_trunc('year', fisy.date)  AS int4) = cast(c."year" as int4)
```

but I get a error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CAST"
```

If I do not include cast, then I get a `syntax error on "ON".`

Comment: "2,011" is the comma a typo?

Comment: @Vallo unfortunately no.

Comment: @Vallo sorry I edited my answer, the year in table2 is a int4

Comment: please add `CREATE TABLE` statements or table definitions of the relevant columns and example data

Comment: also, please provide the full statement

Comment: I would try to first try to create a view on `table2` that returns said column as a date type. After you achieve that, creating the join should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to *extract* the year:

```
extract(year from table1.date) = table2."year"
```

Comment: I got 'SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "on"
  Position: 1167
  ERROR: syntax error at or near "on"
  Position: 1167
  ERROR: syntax error at or near "on"
  Position: 1167
'

Comment: @Lostsoul . . . There is no `on` clause in this answer.  There is no `on` in your question.  That makes it really hard to make any suggestions about the cause of this error.